# How does Nginx decide which location to handle requests if multiple locations match

Tags: nginx

I have nginx server with two locations:

```
location /service1 {
    rewrite ^/service1/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:xxxx;
}

location ~* /service2(?<stuff>.*)$ {
    rewrite ^ /service2$stuff break;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.X;
}
```

Let's say I have a request `http://hostname/service1/service2`. I notice service2 always handle the request. But I want service 1 to handle it. How to set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to understand how Nginx chooses which location block to handle requests. Please read https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms, very helpful article.

Relevant excerpt from the article

*It is important to understand that, by default, Nginx will serve regular expression matches in preference to prefix matches. However, it evaluates prefix locations first, allowing for the administer to override this tendency by specifying locations using the = and ^~ modifiers.*

In your case you could use ‘location ^~ /service1’

Nginx location matcher - https://nginx.viraptor.info/

Comment: I read this article before asking the question. The fifth modifier actually confused me. Can I understand the thing as regular expression generally has priority. But when ^~ is added, the non regular expression has priority?

Comment: The tool is awesome! It saves my day.